# Data Missing when exporting CSV from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to export web scrape data into a csv file. When I print the data frame all of the data is there but when I got to export to csv only the final inning of the data is exported. I assume it must be something to do with the for loop I am using but I cannot find where I went wrong.

I was hoping that the data frame exports with all of the information that show when I print. I have tried this:

```
#imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

#Getting Website for each game ID in 2023 season
gameID = 598903
while gameID <= 598903: 
    website = f"https://baseball.pointstreak.com/boxscore.html?gameid={gameID}"
    result = requests.get(website)
    content = result.text
    gameID = gameID + 1
    #Convert html with Beatiful Soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    #Get Inning playbyplay Data
    Innings = soup.findAll(class_='pbpinning')
    
#Strip text to clean data
for i in Innings:  
    #Cleaning \n and \t characterS
    data = ", ".join([stripped_strings for stripped_strings in i.stripped_strings])
    #print(data)
    
    #All data is pulled in as single string must structure it by inning then by play
    gamesum = data

    # Split the string into lines
    lines = gamesum.split('\n')

    # Iterate over each line and separate the inning and play
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.split(',', 1)
        inning = parts[0].strip()
        play = parts[1].strip()
        
        #Create a dataframe
        pbpdata = {'Inning': [inning], 'Play by Play': [play]}
        pbpdf = pd.DataFrame(pbpdata)
        print(pbpdf)
    
        #pbpdf.to_csv('baseball_game_play_by_play.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your indentations are correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be with your indentation, but there is something that you should note. You are naming all csv files with the same name, that's why you are seeing only the last result as a csv file. You need to name your csv files in a dynamic manner. For example you can use f-string to name your files and add your desired name to it. In this case you can use your variable `inning` to name the file.

```
pbpdf.to_csv(f'baseball_game_play_by_play_{i}.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense thank you. I would Ideally like to store it game by game so I would like all the innings and play by play in the same data frame when I export. I guess I would have to take it outside the loop cause it iterates through each inning

Comment: That's why I said I'm not sure if the indentations of your code are correct or not.

Comment: Okay thank you for clarifying I'll look through that

Comment: Figured it out, indentations were fine it was looping through the data so only last line would show so I had to append at end of loop to save it